# C++ code working in VS2010 but not in 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I have a pecular problem. Code in my application working without any problem in VS2010 and when I today migrated it to VS2013, it is throwing me an error.

Code is -

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class abc
{
    int value;
public:
    abc() { value = 3;  }
    const int value() const { return ::value(*this); }


    friend const int value(const abc& var){ return var.value; }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    abc obj;
    std::cout<<obj.value();
    return 0;
}
```

It is throwing below errors-

```
Error   1   error C3861: 'value': identifier not found  c:\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp  13  1   ConsoleApplication1
    2   IntelliSense: function "value" cannot be called with the given argument list
            argument types are: (const ABC) c:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp  13  35  ConsoleApplication1
```

I search a lot on StackOverFlow and on Google with no luck.

Comment: Not sure how V2010 is able to compile that code but you have `value` as a member data as well as a member function. That is not legal.

Comment: what are you trying to do? Why so much code for nothing?

Comment: Doesn't compile with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel:

Comment: Please do not edit your question a week later in a way that invalidates the given answers. Instead, try to isolate the problem you are struggling with and post it as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm very surprised this compiled on VS2010. Unless `stdafx.h` contained a function definition/declaration for `value`, you're calling a function that has not been defined within `abc::value()`.

Also, `abc` contains both a data member and a member function named `value`, which is not allowed. To fix the errors, rename the data member `value` to something else (I've chosen to name it `value_`).

Then, provide a declaration of the `friend` function before the definition of `abc`. I've also gotten rid of the top-level `const`s on the function return types.

```
class abc;
int value(const abc& var);

class abc
{
    int value_;
public:
    abc() { value_ = 3;  }
    int value() const { return ::value(*this); }

    friend int value(const abc& var){ return var.value_; }
};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ae34fccd6065c85)

---

Another option, one that I prefer myself, would be to rename the inline `friend` to something other than `value()`, and then call it unqualified.

```
class abc
{
    int value_;
public:
    abc() { value_ = 3;  }
    int value() const { return value_fr(*this); }

    friend int value_fr(const abc& var){ return var.value_; }
};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f64701c1361a2d0d)